# Registering and login function of a student database

Tags: c

I need help because I can't use the student ID registered from staff administrator mode to login to the student interface. Every time I enter the exact one, it still shows as invalid.

This is what I did

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

int main()
{
    char firstName[20], lastName[20], studentID[10];
    int mode2, choice;

    printf("Hello please pick between 1) staff or 2) student mode > \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf("What do you want to do?\n");
        printf("1) Enter student's detail\nn2) Logout\n3) Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &mode2);

        printf("Enter the student's first name. > \n");
        scanf("%s", &firstName);
        printf("Enter the student's last name. >\n");
        scanf("%s", &lastName);
        printf("Enter student's student ID. >\n");
        scanf("%s", studentID);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("Student record stored!\n");

        main();
    }

    else if (choice == 2) {

        printf("Welcome student!\n");
        char iD[10];

        printf("Please enter your student ID to proceed. > ");
        scanf("%s", iD);

        if (iD == studentID)
        {


            printf("=======================\n");
            printf("Welcome, student. You have successfully logged in.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid student ID.");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: How to use scanf to read a string [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/c-programming/c-scanf-read-string/#gsc.tab=0).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make your code a [mre]. Currently it is far from minimal. Preferably put everything into a single source file and copy&paste it as a single code block to make it easy for us to compile and run your code. Show the input you use, the actual output you get and the expected output, all as text in code blocks.

Comment: @Bodo hello, is this fine now?

Comment: @tadman hello sorry, i've edited it as best as I can

Comment: @Oka hello! i'll give it a read! thank you for being resourceful :)

Comment: The smaller code is better now, but you can probably remove some of the `scanf` calls and related variables.  Still missing are the input, actual and expected output.

Comment: The other issues include: `scanf("%s", &firstName);` and `scanf("%s", &lastName);` should not use the *address-of* operator with the array variables (i.e., `scanf("%s", lastName);`), recursively calling `main` is very poor form - use a loop (`for`, `while`) instead, and `rewind(stdin);` is dubious, as standard input is generally a non-seekable stream. Research how to turn your compiler warning level up, and don't ignore diagnostic messages, as it would catch some of these issues very early (in short, `gcc -Wall -Wextra`, or at least `/W4` with `msvc`).

Comment: As an aside, faced with this prompt for the first time, I don't see how students would not select 1 just to see what happens.